# Another way to string_split

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like below

```
SELECT vals.*
FROM table AS rels
INNER JOIN table AS vals ON vals.Id IN (
    SELECT value
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(rels.relatedID, ',')
)
WHERE rels.Id = 'x'
```

I want to avoid using `STRING_SPLIT` method here. Is there any possible way for it?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid using `STRING_SPLIT`?

Comment: client sql server not support to this . but we do not want to make any changes there .

Comment: Please add that to your question, along with the version of SQL Server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternative for String\_split in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51090031/alternative-for-string-split-in-sql-server)

Comment: And please stop adding JavaScript snippets for SQL - they don't work.

Comment: I'm lost.  Why are you using a self join?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT vals.*
FROM table rels INNER JOIN
     table vals
     ON CONCAT(',', rels.relatedID, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,', vals.Id, ',%') 
WHERE rels.Id = 'x';
```

However, your efforts should be put to **fixing the data model**.  Storing multiple values in a string column is just the wrong way to store data in a SQL database.

Answer (score -1):

You can create function like below. Here in below `CTE` `f` is starting index and `t` is ending index of string each one separated by `Delimiter`.

Then loop over `CTE` and applied `SUBSTRING` to your original string and returned the result.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]    
(
    @String nvarchar(max), 
    @Delimiter char(1)
)
RETURNS @t table (value nvarchar(max), sequence int)
AS
BEGIN

    SET @String += @Delimiter

    ;WITH a AS
    (
        SELECT CAST(1 AS bigint) f, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String) t, 1 seq
        UNION ALL
        SELECT t + 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, t + 1), seq + 1
        FROM a
        WHERE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @String, t + 1) > 0
    )
    
    INSERT @t
    SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, f, t - f), seq 
    FROM a
    OPTION (maxrecursion 0)
    
    RETURN
    
END
```